# Silverlight MouseLeave showing inconistent behaviour

Tags: silverlight, mouseleave

So, my problem is that the MouseLeave event only gets triggered if I move my cursor at a certain speed. Below is a Thumb with a Border. Click the thumb and keep the mouse button down. Move slowly outside the border = no event, Move fast outside the border = event.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Width="200" Height="100"
            MouseLeave="Border_MouseLeave">
            <Thumb  />
    </Border>
</Grid>


private void Border_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Border_MouseLeave");
}
```

Is it a bug in silverlight or am I missing something?
Thanx
/Mike

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do, but might want to look into using CaptureMouse

Comment: Seen the same issue. Works fine in WPF but not in Silverlight. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a solution or a workaround :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for the anwers, here's an update:
It seems to have something to do with MouseCapture as Guy suggests. The reason being that I also get the problem using Button or a Rectangle that captures the mouse in code-behind.

If I put a Grid between the Thumb and the Border the problem disappears so I think I will go with that.

I also noticed a related problem as I played around some.

```
        <Grid Width="200" Height="100" Background="Transparent" 
              MouseLeave="Border_MouseLeave">                
              <Button  />                
              <Rectangle Width="40" Height="40" Fill="Violet"               
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left" />            
         </Grid>
```

If I press the left button and move the cursor to the left over the Rectangle and out the MouseLeave event is not registered.

This is all very strange.